# Alias with whitespace in fish shell

Tags: fish

I would like to add an alias with a whitespace in fish, like so:

```
alias hello there 'print hello there'
```

Is this in any way possible? (I know this example is invalid, I'm just giving an example).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @faho explained how to do this but I'm curious why you want to do this? The only way to use it is to quote the command name and it seems like it would just be simpler to use a hyphen or underscore instead of a space.

Comment: If this were supported without having to quote, it would be useful for subcommands, like expanding `git diff` -> `git diff --word-diff`.  After typing `git diff` I don't want to have to backtrack to add a hyphen.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "expand". In fish only abbreviations created with the `abbr` command are expanded on the command line. Functions created by the `alias` command are not expanded. They are effectively commands. And like any other command that includes whitespace you would have to quote the command to use it as @faho pointed out in their answer. The usual solution is to create an abbreviation that expands to the longer form; e.g., `abbr ht 'hello there'`. Now you can just type `ht` followed by a space and it will be expanded to "hello there ".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is currently not possible with fish's `alias` wrapper function.

However, what that ends up doing anyway is defining a function, so you could just do that.

```
function "hello there"
    echo hello there
end
```

Execute with `"hello there"` or `hello\ there`.